# Running a java application (JAR file) on commandline, have errors that I don't understand

Tags: java, command-line, jar, enums

Not sure what these errors mean as I have searched some of them such as "Exception NO enum constant" but only "no enum const class" comes up answered on google. Can anyone examine the error at the bottom of command prompt and tell me what the error might be from? Image of the cmd error attached below.

[image: Errors on command prompt running JAR file]

As requested I have put the source code for org.evosuite.Properties.Algorithm which showed that there was an enum error. The entire class is too big but innside algorithm I have alreayd put "CELLULARGA" and the rest of the types of algorithms run so I'm unsure why there is that exception error when I run with cellularGA

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
// Search algorithm
public enum Algorithm {
    STANDARDGA, MONOTONICGA, ONEPLUSONEEA, STEADYSTATEGA, RANDOM, NSGAII,   MOSA, CELLULARGA
}
```

Comment: This looks like you gave it an invalid command line parameter. It does not like "CellularGA". No idea what the valid options are for this particular application (Evosuite?).

Comment: Have you the source code?

Comment: @Thilo: agree. Perhaps this constant `CellularGA` not exists in the enum Algorithm. Algorithm not implemented? Java version? Application version?

Comment: please post source of the `org.evosuit.properties.Algorithm`

Comment: yes ok i will edit and post the source code, it is up in the original message with some of the code of org.evosuite.Properties.Algorithm

Comment: did you add the `;` after `CELLULARGA`? this is not there in the code you have posted.

Comment: Maybe it's an old version of the jar file (which did not have CellularGA yet)?

Comment: thanks for the help guys, and yeah i checked its compiled after cellularga is added, but its weird it just doesn't see that class or something

Answer (score 0):

It's an IllegalArgumentException, which means you have passed in wrong arguments (probably due to type mismatch) to some method in your code. And it says it's on line 238 so you should start there.

You should practice catching exceptions with code that you can understand and which gives you a clearer picture of where the problem is instead of just printing a stacktrace you clearly can't interpret. 
Except it's a runtime exception, in which case you might just have to study them.

Also, you would get more help here if you showed us some source code...